# Prevent section heading to subtitle transformation in reStructuredText

Tags: documentation, markup, restructuredtext

In reStructuredText, a heading followed by a lower-level heading is read as a subtitle:

```
Section 1
=========

Subtitle
--------
```

However, what if I actually want a subsection heading to follow immediately after a section heading? According to the [the docs](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#empty-comments), an empty comment *"serves to terminate a preceding construct"*, but this doesn't seem to apply here, as

```
Section 1
=========

..

Section 2
---------
```

still gets turned into a heading for *Section 1*, followed by a subtitle *Section 2* by, for example, `rst2latex` and `pandoc`.

Is there another way to prevent "subtitlisation" without writing any actual text between the section and subsection headings?

Comment: I think that adding another section title with the same style of decoration as your "Section 2" heading will prevent this heading from becoming a subtitle. In other workds and a new heading, say "Section 3" and use dashes, `-` to denote that it is a heading. "Section 2" and "Section 3" should then be the same heading level. Also, I think you need an additional dash under your "Section 2" heading. It should be at least as long as the title.

Comment: @Chris: That's a good idea as well, thank you. Why did you post it as a comment instead of an answer, though? Your comment answers my question and isn't specific to some mistake I made or anything like that.

Comment: I was not able to test this, so didn't want to post an answer in case it was incorrect. If this does indeed answer your question then I can post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured it out. A backslash followed by a space will work:

```
Section 1
=========

\ 

Section 2
--------
```

I got the idea from a [tip on Simple Tables](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#simple-tables) in the spec:

> To start a new row in a simple table without text in the first column in the processed output, use one of these:
>
> - an empty comment (".."), which may be omitted from the processed output (see [Comments](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#comments) below)
> - a backslash escape ("\") followed by a space (see [Escaping Mechanism](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#escaping-mechanism) above)

IMHO this isn't very consistent: The second method works for breaking up title and subtitle, whereas the first one doesn't, as I stated in my question.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is a side effect: an empty paragraph in the output that may show up as additional space.