# How to create proper heading levels with rst2html

Tags: html, restructuredtext, docutils

I don't understand why:

```
H1: document title
##################

Sample H2
*********
Sample content.
```

results in:

```
<div class="document" id="h1-document-title">
<h1 class="title">H1: document title</h1>
<h2 class="subtitle" id="sample-h2">Sample H2</h2>

<p>Sample content.</p>
</div>
```

whereas

```
H1: document title
##################

Sample H2
*********
Sample content.

Sample H3
*********
Sample content.
```

Results in:

```
<div class="document" id="h1-document-title">
<h1 class="title">H1: document title</h1>

<div class="section" id="sample-h2">
<h1>Sample H2</h1>
<p>Sample content.</p>
</div>
<div class="section" id="sample-h3">
<h1>Sample H3</h1>
<p>Sample content.</p>
</div>
```

i.e. I cannot have a h1 element followed by more than one h2. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is about the interpretation of document title and subtitle. If the adornment for the first heading is unique within the document, it is interpreted as the document title. If there is a second heading with another unique adornment immediately after the first, it is taken to be the subtitle.

See http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/user/rst/quickstart.html#document-title-subtitle.

Example:

```
Document title
##############

Subtitle
.........

Heading 1
*********
Sample content.

Heading 2
---------
Sample content.

Heading 3
---------
Sample content.
```

From this markup, rst2html will generate HTML with headings as follows:

- Document title: `<h1>` (centered)
- Subtitle: `<h2>` (centered)
- Heading 1: `<h1>`
- Heading 2: `<h2>`
- Heading 3: `<h2>`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. What if we do not need Title and Subtitle, and we want to use only headings?

Comment: OK, I think I found a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23936768/prevent-section-heading-to-subtitle-transformation-in-restructuredtext

Comment: If the adornment used for the first heading is not unique, then you have a document with "only headings".

Comment: If you don't want a document title, you can use the [doctitle-xform](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/user/config.html#doctitle-xform) setting or the corresponding command line option "--no-doc-title" to disable the promotion of a lone top-level section title.